# Constructing an $\omega_1$-sequence of functions that almost extend all previous functions

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

I want to construct a sequence of functions $$f_\alpha: \alpha \rightarrow \omega,\ \alpha < \omega_1$$
such that for all $\alpha < \omega_1$ the following holds:

- $f_\alpha$ is injective.
- $(\forall \beta < \alpha)\ f_\beta =^* f_\alpha \upharpoonright \beta$,

i.e. the restriction $f_\alpha \upharpoonright \beta$ agrees with $f_\beta$ in all but finitely many places.

I feel this should be possible for similar reasons we can construct a family of continuum many almost disjoint subsets of $\omega$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nice question! I like it very much.

Sure, we can do this. We'll also arrange that
$\text{ran}(f_\alpha)$ is coinfinite. That will make the successor
steps easy, since there is always another point available. The
difficulty is what to do at limits. Suppose we have $f_\alpha$ for
$\alpha<\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a countable limit ordinal. We want to define the function $f_\lambda$. In order to do this, pick an increasing cofinal sequence
$\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\cdots<\lambda$ with
$\sup_n\alpha_n=\lambda$. We shall define $f_\lambda$ in blocks. First, let $f_\lambda$ agree with
$f_{\alpha_0}$ up to $\alpha_0$. Next, on the interval
$[\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$, we make $f_\lambda$ agree with
$f_{\alpha_1}$, except modified so that it is still injective in combination with what we already did below $\alpha_0$.
This modification will require only at most finitely many changes to $f_{\alpha_1}\upharpoonright[\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$, since
$f_{\alpha_0}$ and $f_{\alpha_1}$ agree except on a finite set.
Continuing, we define $f_\lambda$ on the interval
$[\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1})$ to agree with $f_{\alpha_{n+1}}$, except
fixed up again to be injective, which will require only finitely many
changes. Ultimately, in this way we'll get an injective function
$f_\lambda:\lambda\to\omega$. For any $\alpha<\lambda$, we have
$\alpha<\alpha_n$ for some $n$, and consequently
$f_\lambda\upharpoonright\alpha$ was obtained from finite
modifications of the $f_{\alpha_k}$'s for $k<n$, each of which had
only finite difference from $f_\alpha$ up to $\alpha$. And so our
function $f_\lambda$ differs from $f_\alpha$ on $\alpha$ only at
most finitely. Lastly, to ensure that $f_\lambda$ has coinfinite
range, we may if necessary simply change the values on the
ordinals $\alpha_n$, since this will involve only finitely many
changes below any given $\alpha<\lambda$. Thus, we have constructed
the function $f_\lambda$ with the desired properties, the
construction may proceed up to $\omega_1$.

Comment: I seem to recall that such a family of functions is used in Stevo Todorcevic's proof that forcing to add a Cohen real creates a Suslin tree.

Comment: It's not difficult to see that the coinfinite range requirement is necessary, because if some $f_\alpha$ has cofinite range in $\omega$, then you will run out of room at some $f_{\alpha+k}$.

Comment: Nice exposition! Actually the statement and proof appear in Kunen's chapter in the Handbook of Mathematical Logic, pp 383-4. Modesty prevents from mentioning also my book Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory.

Comment: The precise references are: Q16, p.113, and its solution, p. 438, Komjath and Totik.

Comment: A really attractive explanation of both the result on $\aleph_1$ almost identical injective functions and its use in the proof of Shelah's theorem that adding a Cohen real creates a Suslin tree is given in Judith Roitman's $\textit{Notes on Forcing}$, Theorem 46: https://www.math.ku.edu/~roitman/996notes.pdf

Comment: Yes, her argument (see page 41) is essentially the same as what I argue above.

Comment: This can also be done at higher successor cardinals $\kappa^+$ where the disagreements are size $<\kappa$. It's a bit more complicated.

Comment: See Monroe's paper on many interesting generalizations of this: http://www.math.uci.edu/~meskew/forests.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Todorcevic' $\rho_2$ Number of Steps function and its related tree $T(\rho_2)$ define a coherent set of functions (discovered by Peng).